# How to convert photo taken by a camera into binary

Tags: android

I want to convert an image taken in phone's camera to binary and use that binary image for further processing. I made an app that will take the photo and save it in gallery.

How can I convert the photo it to binary?

Comment: try it http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/173531/How-to-convert-an-image-into-binary-format-and-sav

Comment: use threshold algrithm

Answer (score 0):

Simple four lines for that:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/imagepath/yourimage.jpg");
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);  
byte[] b = bos.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Take image from camera using below method :**

```
private void fromCamera() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        Log.d("FROM CAMERA CLICKED file uri", fileUri.getPath());
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

        // start the image capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_FROM_CAMERA);
    }
```

**After in onActivityResult()**

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_FROM_CAMERA
                && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            try {


                image_path = fileUri.getPath();

                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_path);
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object   
                byte[] b = baos.toByteArray(); 

            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } 
}
```